# Passing Data stored in store from a Page to another using Redux (React Native)

Tags: react-native, redux

I have been trying to trying to get this to work. 
But, it seems all other questions here are not helping me resolve the issue.

I have uploaded my code. What am I doing wrong, please?

**loginAction.js**

```
export const SET_LOGIN_DATA = 'SET_LOGIN_DATA';

export const setLoginData = data => {
return {
    type: SET_LOGIN_DATA,
    login_data: data
}
};
```

**loginReducer.js**

```
 import SET_LOGIN_DATA from '../actions/loginAction'
 import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

const loginReducer = (state = {}, action = {}) => {

 switch (action.type) {

    case SET_LOGIN_DATA:
        state = action.login_data;
        return state || {};

    default:
        return state;
}
}

 export default loginReducer;
```

**configureStore.js**

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';

import loginReducer from './redux/reducers/loginReducer';

const configureStore = (initialState = {}) => (
createStore(
    combineReducers({
        login: loginReducer,
    }),
    initialState,
)
);

export default configureStore;
```

**UserLogin.js**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';
 import ButtonComponent from './buttonComponent';
 import setLoginData from './redux/actions/loginAction';
 import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

  class UserLogin extends Component {
   static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'User Login',
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        alignSelf: 'center',
    },
};

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        useremail: 'user',
        userpassword: '1234',
    }
};   

handleSubmit() {
    let data  = this.state;
    //this.props.onLogin({ data });
    setLoginData(data);
};


   render() {
      return (
        <View>
            <View style={{ borderRadius: 10 }}>
                <TextInput style={styles.input}
                    //value={this.state.useremail}
                    placeholder="Email"
                    placeholderTextColor="#1c4382"
                    onChangeText={(useremail) => this.setState({ useremail 
               })}
                    onSubmitEditing={() => { this.handleSubmit}}
                    >
                </TextInput>
            </View>

            <View style={{ borderRadius: 10 }}>
                <TextInput style={styles.input}
                    //value={this.state.userpassword}
                    placeholder="Password"
                    placeholderTextColor="#1c4382"
                    onChangeText={(userpassword) => this.setState({ 
               userpassword })}
                    onSubmitEditing={() => { this.handleSubmit}}
                    >
                </TextInput>
            </View>

            <ButtonComponent onButtonPressed={this.handleSubmit} 
 text="Submit" textcolor='#fff' borderColor='#fff' 
    backgroundColor='#0d8cdb'> 
 </ButtonComponent>

        </View>
    );
   }
 }

   const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return {
         login_data: state.login
      }
   }

  const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
    bindActionCreators({
      setLoginData
    }, dispatch)
 );
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    height: 40,
    borderColor: '#1c4382',
    borderWidth: 1,
    width: 200,
    alignItems: 'center',
    margin: 10,
    padding: 10,
  },
});


export default LoginContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps)
  (UserLogin);
```

**Todo.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';
import Login from './Login';
import UserLogin from './UserLogin';
import LoginContainer from './UserLogin';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { setLoginData } from './redux/actions/loginAction';

import { ITEMS } from './assets/goodies/data';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

export default class Todo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        places: ITEMS,
    }
}

static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'To do',
    headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#f4511e',
    },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    headerTitleStyle: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        alignSelf: 'center',
    },
};


render() {
    //const { state } = this.props.navigation;
    //console.log("New user " + state.params.placeusername + " logged in 
 with password " + state.params.placeusername)
    var message = "New user " + this.props.login_data.useremail + " logged 
in with password " + this.props.login_data.userpassword;
    const renderItems = ({ item, index }) => {
        var des = item.latitude + " " + item.longitude
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row" }}>
                <View style={{
                    flex: 0.1,
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    alignItems: "center"
                }}>
                    <Icon name='delete' />
                </View>
                <View style={{ flex: 0.9 }}>
                    <ListItem
                        key={index}
                        title={item.name}
                        description={des}
                    />
                </View>

                <View style={styles.separator} />
                <Text>
                    {this.message}
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

And I am trying to pass the data from this UserLogin.js to Todo.js
On Todo.js, I get the error:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.login_data.useremail')

And for UserLogin.js, on clicking the submit button, I get the error:

> undefined is not a function (evaluating '(0,S.default)(t)')

What am I setting wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

- In the Todo file you don't connect to the redux store, so *this.props.login_data.useremail* will always be null
- In the handleSubmit function of UserLogin you should use

> this.props.setLoginData(data)

instead of

> setLoginData(data)

Comment: Thanks for your response but I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Let's try with this u can need to dispatch the ur action.

```
handleSubmit() {
    let data  = this.state;
    let {dispatch}=this.props;
    dispatch(setLoginData(data));
};
```